# How to pass values from one xaml page to another in a Metro style app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have two XAML pages: Menu.xaml and Main.xaml.

On Menu.xaml, I have 2 buttons (Easy & Hard) and when I click the buttons, I navigate to Main.xaml.

I want to pass some value when I click 'Easy' or 'Hard', 
so that I can populate Main.xaml appropriately.

1. How can I pass values/arguments in C#? 
 2. Where do I retrieve these values (e.g. on PageLoad?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `Frame.Navigate` methods. There is an overload that lets you pass in a parameter.

[See this for an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx)

Typically this would look something like this:

```
private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (sender == easyButton)
      NavigateToDifficulty(DifficultyLevel.Easy);
    else
      NavigateToDifficulty(DifficultyLevel.Hard);
}

private void NavigateToDifficulty(DifficultyLevel difficulty)
{
   this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(DifficultyPage), difficulty)
}
```

To retrieve the navigation parameter look at the `LayoutAwarePage` (included in the sample templates) `LoadState` method

Answer (score 3):

Navigation is pretty simple in a Metro App.

C# Example:

Add this to your click or whatever other event takes you to the main page.

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Main),myDifficulty);
```

Then on the page you're navigating to, you can get the argument in its OnNavigatedTo event.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) 
{ 
    var myDifficulty= e.Parameter; 
    ...    
}
```